# Thurston on the Robertson-Seymour theorem

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, ho.history-overview

Danny Calegari recounts [here](https://lamington.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/bill-thurston-1946-2012/#more-1729) that Bill Thurston "gave one talk explaining his idea of a new proof of (some version of) the Robertson-Seymour theorem" at MSRI in 1996-1997. I could not find it in the extensive video archive of MSRI.

Is there any account of his ideas available somewhere (apart from this blog post)? Or perhaps someone who was present in the audience remembers some bits of it?

Comment: I believe that Dylan has Bill's computer.  Ask him directly - perhaps there are some useful records there?

Comment: It might also be productive to ask Danny. He may have notes, or might remember other participants who may have notes.